# Out of Glass Puzzle (MatchStick Puzzle)

Tags: matches

[image: Fly in a glass]

The object is to move 2 matches to get the bluebottle to fly outside the glass. At the finish, the glass may be turned in any direction, but it must be exactly the **same shape as before**.

Comment: I can move 2 matches, make the fly fly outside the glass, AND keep the glass the very same shape, direction and position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just move the horizontal stick to the left by half width. And right vertical stick to the bottom left to get the glass turned upside-down.

Comment: Symmetrically you can move the horizontal stick to the **right** by half of its length and then the upper left stick to the down right side to reform the glass upside down.

Answer (score 11):

you can do it with the following sequence:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Solution while keeping the glass in shape, direction and position. The fly can't go through walls. So, done!

[image]